# What adaptation of "The Fall of the House of Usher" did I see in the 1980s?

Tags: story-identification, edgar-allan-poe

I remember watching, as a child, in the early or mid 1980s, what I thought was a film adaptation of Edgar Allen Poe's "[The Fall of the House of Usher](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/932/932-h/932-h.htm)."  I don't think we saw the beginning; it was something that we just happened to find on television.  For years, I had thought this was the [Roger Corman 1960 version](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053925/) starring Vincent Price; however, I just watched Corman's film with my daughter, and there were some things that did not agree with what I remembered from the version I had seen.

There were some things about the 1960 movie that matched what I remembered, but there were others that definitely did not.  However, I can find no evidence of any other color adaptations of Poe's story that are early enough to be what I am looking for.  So it is possible that I am conflating elements from two different films, Corman's *House of Usher* and some other work.  Naturally, if that is the case, I would like to know what was other work (the source of the divergent elements) actually was.

There were things in Corman's movie that agreed with my memory:  The color palette used a lot of red.  Roderick Usher was convinced that the physical house in which the Ushers lived was actively evil.  His sister was eventually locked up, but she escaped and came back to get her revenge.  The visiting protagonist eventually escapes from the doomed house, which is gutted by fire.

However, my memories did not match the Corman version in a number of respects as well:  The sister (I don't remember if her name was "Madeline" or not) had long blond hair and was definitely evil, not merely a victim of Roderick's machinations who was driven to madness by being sealed alive in a coffin.  She also wielded a spiked flail as a weapon at some point and cried tears of blood.  (Corman's version focuses quite a bit on Madeline's eyes, which are heavily reddened, but there are no actual bloody tears.)  Finally, my clearest memory is that after the house was engulfed in flames, the protagonist had to make his escape through a secret passage.  Roderick's death occurs in the library, and as he was dying, with the house already engulfed in fire, Roderick revealed that the escape passage could be opened by moving a book on one of the shelves.  "Pull out the book *Black Arts*," he said.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"The Fall of the House of Usher" (1979 TV movie)?

This was a made for television movie which was made in 1979, but according to IMDb.com it was not shown until 1982 (which matches the time you saw it). It starred Martin Landau as Usher. It is available on YouTube in 7 different parts. Here is part 7, the conclusion, where you can see the mad Madeline with blonde hair, using a spiked flail and crying tears of blood.

Comment: Thanks!  Bizarrely, searching IMDB for "house of usher" does not bring this up for me.

Comment: Thanks Buzz! If this was the one, please accept it as best answer.

Comment: I'm confident it is, but I'm going to watch it first.